# PL/SQL how can ı create string function=

Tags: oracle, function, plsql

In the desired structure, the function will take 2 string parameters.

- If 2nd String is found in 1st String; The 1.string in the 2.string will be removed and added to the end of the 2.string.
- If it is not found, the error 'NOT FOUND' will be given.

The desired structure should be as follows.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one option:

```
SQL> create or replace function f_test (par_1 in varchar2, par_2 in varchar2)
  2    return varchar2
  3  is
  4    retval varchar2(20);
  5  begin
  6    if instr(par_1, par_2) > 0 then
  7       retval := replace(par_1, par_2) || par_2;
  8    else
  9       retval := 'Not found';
 10    end if;
 11
 12    return retval;
 13  end;
 14  /

Function created.

SQL>
SQL> select f_test('topualiat', 'ali' ) result_1,
  2         f_test('little'   , 'foot') result_2
  3  from dual;

RESULT_1        RESULT_2
--------------- ---------------
topuatali       Not found

SQL>
```